# Verificar se o texto digitado já existe em um arquivo de texto em um site

Tags: vb.net

Quero que o VB verifique se o username digitado já exite em um aquivo de texto hospedado em um site. Quero algo parecido com isso:

```
Dim Findstring = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\server\users.txt")
Dim Lookfor As String = FlatTextBox1.Text

if Findstring.Contains(Lookfor) Then
   ErroUserExist.ShowDialog()
```

Só que ao invés de procurar pelo txt no meu pc, eu quero que ele busque em um site. Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez isto possa te ajudar:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Management

Public Class Form1

    Dim Web As New WebClient
    Dim Endereco As String = "http://exemplo.com"
    Dim Server As String = Endereco & "txt/"
    Dim Usuarios As String = Web.DownloadString(Server & "usuarios.txt")

    If Usuarios.Contains(FlatTextBox1.Text) Then
        ErroUserExist.ShowDialog()
    End If
End Class
```

Comment: Opa, valeu amigo, ajudou bastante.